# Is there any way to simplify field initialization?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

So I was wondering if I can simplify this somehow as it's taking a lot of space on screen:

```
private Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<double>>> storage = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<double>>>();
```

Comment: not for fields.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use an alias for it.

```
using System;
// and others
using MyDict = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, System.Collections.Generic.List<double>>>;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var a = new MyDict();
        }
    }
}
```

or you can do it like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    using MyDict = Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<double>>>;

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var a = new MyDict();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Even more code now but at least I can hide that at the top, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new class derived from the long-winded datatype, and use that instead.

```
public class NumberStorage : Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<double>>>
{
}
```

and then

```
private NumberStorage storage = new NumberStorage();
```

- Aliases (the `using` keyword) must be declared in each file.
- The advantage of creating a new class is that it only has to be done once.